# How Parent View Model Store Load and bind to child grid component in Sencha Architect ExtJs 5.1?

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, grid, extjs5

I am new in using Extjs 5 with Sencha Architect 3.x, 
I have a grid component within a Center panel having a Store defined in its ViewModel. for e,g,

```
CenternPanel - MainVMStore  - here JSON store is defined
ChildComponent1 Grid bind with MainVMStore      
ChildComponent2 Grid also bind with MainVMStore
```

Here childcomponents(1 & 2) is linked to CenterPanel, so they have their own View Models, when placing store in their individual view model it loads with data nicely by calling like

```
var store=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#grid1')[0].getViewModel('grid1VM').getStore('storename');
store.load();
```

But not when define single store in center view model.

also, I am not able to get how to load the store explicitly. I tried like

```
var store=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#grid1')[0].getView().getViewModel('centerVM').getStore('storename') -- this does not work
```

Please help me finding solution..also please suggest me the better way (with example if any)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide anything too useful from what you've provided, but your one-liners are quite lengthy. Try something like this:

```
var store = this.down('#grid1').getStore();
```

or

```
var store = this.queryById('#grid1').getStore(); // # probably not required, I'm going from memory here
```